# Get data attribute value with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I currently have an li like so:

```
<li value="100" data-cost="137.00"><span>100</span></li>
```

I am trying to access the data attribute cost value.
In this example I would like to get a return of 137.00

I am doing a console log of this since I thought this would work:

```
console.log($(this).closest("[data-cost]"));
```

My return shows the entire object and I can see the dataset there:
[image]

The reason I'm using closest is because I currently need to select this li when it's clicked so I'm using span to select it.

This is the entire code block to select an element.

```
  $(function(){
    jQuery(".po-list li span").on("click", function(){
      var span = $(this).clone();
      var options_col = $(this).closest('.options-col');
      console.log($(this).closest("[data-cost]"));
      span.attr('class','cur-option-val');
      options_col.find('.cur-option-w .cur-option-val').replaceWith(span);
    });
  });
```

As I said above I was expecting this: 
console.log($(this).closest("[data-cost]")); to return just the value.
I tried this:

```
console.log($(this).closest("[data-cost]").val());
console.log($(this).closest("[data-cost]").text());

Both of those returned the value of the span not of the data-cost
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).closest("[data-cost]")` will just return the element with the attribute of `data-cost` - which you can see. Use the `.data()` method to extract the value:

```
$(this).closest("[data-cost]").data("cost");
```

<s>This will return a string representation of what's in the attribute. If you need it as a number - cast it:</s>

```
//Ignore this, casting wasn't needed as pointed out in comments
//let dataCost = +$(this).closest("[data-cost]").data("cost"); //the "+" will cast the string to a number
```

Edit: As Barmar pointed out, `.data()` will already do the parsing.

Comment: You don't need to cast it. `.data()` will try to parse it as JSON, and if it's valid it will return the parsed value.

Comment: @Barmar - Edited the post, didn't know that, thanks!